# Android Landscape ConstraintLayout View Not Displaying Properly

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout, landscape

I am very new to android development, but have manged to get my app working, except for the startup of the application. It is a full screen app, that connects to a remote database and displays this information in both Landscape or Portrait orientations. When starting in portrait it works fine, even if there is a problem connecting to the database. When starting or switching to landscape the view is not completed when there is an issue connecting to the database (via a connToDb.post(connToDbCode) runnable), but finally looks OK after connecting (where another runnable is used to periodically query the database).

I cannot post images, so ... The view shows various boxes with a gradient filled rectangle backgrounds with various elements within each box (text, images, etc.). The view /boxes are not fit to the screen properly, and the background gradient-filled rectangles seem to be their original sizes (i.e., not expanded to fill the boxes). In other words the view does not get finished drawing properly. It all looks fine in Android Studio, and also after the database connection is established.

I don't understand:

- Why it works fine in portrait?
- Why it works on API 26 and not API 21
- Why it works fine after the database connection is established?
- What the possible causes and solutions may be (I've tried many!)?

The start of the large landscape layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mywxLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="mywx.FullscreenActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tempBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/currentTemp"

            android:background="@drawable/rec_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/feelsLike"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/windBox"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="7"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rec_bottom" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/currentWind"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tempBox"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rainBox"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tempBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rec_top" />
```

I have tried everything to resolve this issue, which has arisen a few months or so ago (an update to a library or other issue?).

I am using Android Studio V4.1.1, and all other libraries are up-to-date as of 12 Nov 2020.

Comment: It appears as if the Measure pass followed by the Layout pass are not done ... why?

Answer (score 0):

Wow ... found the error. There was a problem with one of the translations of a default Text String! Fixed that, but then had to do a "File/ Invalidate Caches / Restart ..."

So, bottom line ... if the display isn't behaving as expected, check your Text values for Wrap_content text items in your layout!